# Will my Java SDK app work in BusinessObjects XIr2?

Tags: java, sdk, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I got a sample application from the SAP site which uses the SDK that comes with BusinessObjects.  I modified it to move reports from one folder to another folder.  It used to delete reports.  It uses the `getSessionManager()` method and it uses the `IInfoObhects` interface.  The sample was written in 2010 for I believe BO XI3.1, and the modification I tested on BI4.1, it works nicely. It moves the report using the `setParent()` method.

Problem is, the client is on XIr2.  I am hoping the code is simple enough that it will be backward compatible to the XIr2 SDK.  Does anyone have any insight here? Are there some surefire ways I can tell if it will work with the XIr2 SDK, short of deploying it and watching it break?  Is there a way I can be sure it might work?

thanks so much
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the XIr2 Javadocs [here](https://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xir2/boe/en/index.html).  If you're going to run it against an XIr2 system, you will need the XIr2 SDK (jars) to compile against.  If it's simple enough, it should work - there wasn't much changed in the core SDK between XIr2 and XI3.